# How to expand macros in `tests` folder

Tags: rust, rust-macros

How to use `cargo expand` to expand macros on test files under the `tests` folder in a crate?

```
crate
    - src
        - lib.rs
    - tests
        - my_test.rs
    Cargo.toml
```

`cargo expand --lib --tests` do not recognize them(?). `--bin` doesn't recognize them neither.

In `my_test.rs`:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_it() {
    assert!(true);
}
```

`cargo expand --test test_it` replies with `error: no test target named test_it`

Do I have to add something to `Cargo.toml` so they are included?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to expand the macros in my tests using:

`cargo expand --test tests`, perhaps try `cargo expand --test my_test`

The project is similar to yours:

```
crate
    - src
        - lib.rs
    - tests
        - tests.rs
    Cargo.toml
```

Cargo version: 1.69.0-nightly